# OpenLayers is not showing the additional layer

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I am trying to implement [openportguide](http://openportguide.de/index.php/en/) layers on osm. Instead of adding layers one by one I created a function that gets the values and create url based on selection. So far it is not working.Couldn't figure out what is the problem.

Html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Js:

```
window.app = {};
    var app = window.app;
    //Custom Controls

    var layers = [];

    app.WeatherControl = function (opt_options) {
        var options = opt_options || {};

            //Weather Layers
            var weatherUI = document.createElement('div');
            weatherUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        weatherUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
        weatherUI.className = 'weatherui ol-unselectable ol-control';
        weatherUI.id = 'weatherlayerid';
        weatherUI.style.zIndex = '3';
            weatherUI.title = 'Please Select a Weather Layer';
        var weatherText = document.createElement('div');
        weatherText.style.zIndex = '3';
        weatherText.innerHTML = '<table style="background-color:rgba(0,60,136,.5)" id="weatherlayers"><tbody><tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable"><th id="weathertilestitle"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Weather Layers <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th></tr></tbody><tbody style="text-align: center" id="accordion" class="collapse"><tr><td id="layergroupnames">Common</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="wind_stream" data-opacity="1"><label for="wind_stream">Wind Stream</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="wind_barb" data-opacity="1"><label for="wind_barb">Wind Barbs</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="gust" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="gust">Wind Gust</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="air_temperature" data-opacity="1"> <label for="air_temperature">Air Temp.</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="surface_pressure" data-opacity="1"><label for="surface_pressure">Surface Pressure</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="precipitation" data-opacity="1"><label for="precipitation">Precipitation</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="precipitation_shaded" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="precipitation_shaded">Precipitation(S)</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="significant_wave_height" data-opacity="1"><label for="significant_wave_height">Wave Height</label></td></tr><tr><td id="layergroupnames">Marine</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="primary_wave_height_direction" data-opacity="1"><label for="primary_wave_height_direction">Wave Direction</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="primary_wave_period" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="primary_wave_period"></label>Wave Period</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="swell_height_direction" data-opacity="1"><label for="swell_height_direction">Swell Direction</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="swell_period" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="swell_period"></label>Swell Period</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="sea_surface_current" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="sea_surface_current"></label>Currents</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="sea_surface_temperature" data-opacity="1"><label for="sea_surface_temperature"></label>Sea Temp.</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="sea_ice_coverage" data-opacity="0.3"><label for="sea_ice_coverage"></label>Ice Coverage</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="sea_ice_thickness" data-opacity="1"><label for="sea_ice_thickness"></label>Ice Thickness</td></tr><tr><td id="layertime">Time</td><td><input type="radio" id="h0" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="0h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)" checked=""><label id="0h_label" for="0h">Current</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h6" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="6h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="6h_label" for="6h">6h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h12" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="12h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="12h_label" for="12h">12h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h24" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="24h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"> <label id="24h_label" for="24h">24h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h36" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="36h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="36h_label" for="36h">36h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h48" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="48h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="48h_label" for="48h">48h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h60" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="60h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="60h_label" for="60h">60h</label></td><td><input type="radio" id="h72" class="timecheckbox" name="time" value="72h" onclick="TimeButtonClicked(this)"><label id="72h_label" for="72h">72h</label></td></tr></tbody></table><div style="display:none" id="graph-windbeaufort"> <div id="scale-title">Beaufort Scale</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">3</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">6</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">8</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">9</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">11</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">12</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-windgust"> <div id="scale-title">Gust - Beaufort Scale</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">3</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">6</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">8</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">9</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">11</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">12</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level14"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">13</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level15"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">14</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level16"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">15</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level17"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">16</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level18"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">17</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-precipitation"> <div id="scale-title">Precipitation Scale - mm/h</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">20</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">40</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">70</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-waveheight"> <div id="scale-title">Wave & Swell Height(m)</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1.5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">3</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">6</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">8</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">9</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level14"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">11</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level15"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">12</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level16"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">13</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level17"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">14</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level18"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">15</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level19"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">16</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level20"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">17</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level21"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">18</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level22"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">19</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level23"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">20</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-waveperiod"> <div id="scale-title">Wave & Swell Period(s)</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">6</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">8</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">12</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">14</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">16</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">18</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">20</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">22</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">24</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level14"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">26</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level15"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">28</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level16"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">30</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-currents"> <div id="scale-title">Currents(kn)</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0.5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1.5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">2.5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">3</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">4</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">5</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">6</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level12"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">7</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level13"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">8</div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="graph-icecover"> <div id="scale-title">Ice Coverage(%)</div><div class="graph-section graph-level1"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">0</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level2"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">1</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level3"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">10</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level4"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">20</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level5"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">30</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level6"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">40</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level7"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">50</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level8"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">60</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level9"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">70</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level10"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">80</div></div><div class="graph-section graph-level11"> <div class="graph-bar"></div><div class="graph-caption">90</div></div></div>';
            weatherUI.appendChild(weatherText);

        $('input[id="wind_stream"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-windbeaufort").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="wind_barb"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-windbeaufort").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="gust"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-windgust").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="precipitation_shaded"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-precipitation").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="primary_wave_height_direction"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-waveheight").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="swell_height_direction"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-waveheight").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="primary_wave_period"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-waveperiod").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="swell_period"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-waveperiod").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="sea_surface_current"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-currents").toggle(this.checked) });

        $('input[id="sea_ice_coverage"]', weatherText).click(function () { $("#graph-icecover").toggle(this.checked) });


        $('input:radio', weatherText).click(function (e) {
                map.getOverlays().clear();
                var ly = $("#weatherlayers input[type='checkbox']:checked");
                $.each(ly, function (i, val) {
                    updateLayers(val);
                })
        });

        $('input:checkbox', weatherText).click(function (e) {
                updateLayers(this);
        });  

        function updateLayers(control) {
            var base_URL = 'http://weather.openportguide.de/tiles/actual/';
            var checked = control.checked;
            var time = $("#weatherlayers  input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            var opacity = $(control).data("opacity");
            var layername = control.id;
            for (_layer in map.getOverlays().getArray()) {
                if (map.getOverlays().getAt(_layer).title == layername + time) {
                    if (checked == false) {
                        map.getOverlays().removeAt(_layer);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (checked == false)
                return;
            var weatheroverlaylayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: layername + time,
                visible: false,
                opacity: opacity,
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    url: base_URL + layername + "/" + time + "/" + "{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                })
            })

            layers.push(weatheroverlaylayer);

        };

        ol.control.Control.call(this, {
            element: weatherUI,
            target: options.target
        });

        $('[data-toggle="collapse"]', weatherText).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $('#accordion').toggle() });

    };
    ol.inherits(app.WeatherControl, ol.control.Control);

 var oSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

layers.push(oSM);

var map = new ol.Map({
      controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new app.WeatherControl()
        ]),
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-5.3525700, 36.1447400]),
          zoom: 6
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this row:

> layers.push(weatheroverlaylayer);

Because it is in a function that is called on user click, it is after the map initialization. When initializing map you can specify layers that are added to the map in the moment of initialization. When the map is already initialized you have to use function

> map.addLayer(weatheroverlaylayer)

which adds layer to allready defined map. Doc is [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#addLayer).